# How to make 2 list views in a tab widget

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I made a list view by the android.com's tutorial, and its in a tab widget, but the problem is that its spreading all over the tab's area and I want to create 2 lists in one tab, one beside the other... how can I do that?
here is a link to the tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

**EDIT:** ok that what I have in the onCreate method, there are 2 static final String arrays in this class called CONTACTS and FAVORITES, I copied MH's layout to an xml file called list_who and changed the IDs to lv_cons and lv_vav, and another layout called tv (TextView) that only have a text view because that what the adapter requires

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ListView lv_cons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_cons);
ListView lv_fav = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_fav);
lv_cons.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tv, CONTACTS));
lv_fav.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tv, FAVORITES));
setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.list_who));
```

Comment: Do you want two tabs with a list in each or two lists in one tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two display two lists side-by-side, there are a few things you'll need to change.

First the (minimal) layout for the tab's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you followed the Hello ListView sample code you linked, you'll have to change your `ListActivity` back to `Activity`. The former basically offers a number of convenience methods for working with a *single* list, but you can do exactly the same with a regular activity, which you'll need to work with multiple lists.

You can inflate your ListViews like any other view by using their ids (there is no more `getListView()` convenience method, since we're not extending ListActivity anymore)`:

```
ListView leftList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_listview);
ListView rightList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_listview);
```

From that point on you can add all stuff to populate/manipulate the lists' contents.

**//Edit:** If you insist on creating the layout programmatically, simple convert above xml code to it's Java equivalent:

```
// Create ViewGroup as container for both lists
LayoutParams rootParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
root.setLayoutParams(rootParams);

// Create LayoutParams for the lists - both identical in this example
LinearLayout.LayoutParams listParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
listParams.weight = 1;
ListView leftList = new ListView(this);
ListView rightList = new ListView(this);
leftList.setLayoutParams(listParams);
rightList.setLayoutParams(listParams);

// Add lists to container
root.addView(leftList);
root.addView(rightList);

// Set container as content view
setContentView(contentView);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I do setContentView to the layout, or set an adapter to the lists, it crashes.

Comment: Then evidently it's time you start adding some of your code to your question. Above should work fine, so you're probably mixing up some other things.

Comment: You have to call `setContentView(...)` before you try to inflate any views. In other words, move that call to right after `super.onCreate(...)`. Think about it like this: how can the Activity try to inflate any views if you haven't told it yet what layout it should be using?

Comment: Ok I moved it to the top but still no luck, and by the debugger it crashed on the seContentVie line, and if I remove it, the app crashes on the setAdapter line.

Comment: Oh I forgot, I don't want to use setContentView, I want to create the Lists from the activity because this activity is a tab in a tabHost, also made by the android.com's tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: "Ok I moved it to the top but still no luck" - that's not what I said; it shouldn't be completely at the top. "Oh I forgot, I don't want to use setContentView" - sorry, that's impossible. "I want to create the Lists from the activity because this activity is a tab in a tabHost" - that's a non-argument to create the layout programmatically. I'm pretty sure that the linked tutorial only does that to shorten and simplify the example code. Anyways, I added some code that does the equivalent of the xml layout...

Comment: Ok thank you very much, but I didn't understabd one thing, where you wrote setContentView(contentView), what did you mean by contentView? root? because if you did than it won't crash, but also it wouldn't show anything...

Comment: I do have one more problem, I want to make an other list, below these two, so I made an other linear layout and made it vertical, and added to it the layout you made in your answer that contain the two first lists, and also I added to the vertical layout I made the third list directly, but I can't see it when I ran the app

Comment: That's probably because the height in horizontally-oriented LinearLayout is set to `FILL_PARENT`. In order for the third list to show up below the first two, you'll want to apply weights again. For a 50/50 ratio, simply set the weights of the children in the outermost LinearLayout to `1` (similar to in the already provided sample code). Obviously you can also change it to any ratio you like, e.g. if the lower list should take up less/more space.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to handle two separate `ListView`s in separate tabs (i.e. a `ListView` in each tab), then follow this tutorial: [Android TabActivity with two list views](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59).

You simply need to make one composite layout and extract your `tabHost` from the xml programmatically and then inflate the tabs on the fly. I further suggest using this method if you want two lists to communicate with each other via an `Intent`. Both tabs would be hosted in one activity. If I misunderstood your question and you want to display two separate, adjacent lists within one activity..then disregard my answer.

I think this is what you're looking for. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you but you did misunderstand, I do want two lists in one tab, i'll be more clear in my question